# c++ windows api current x and y values for the window?

Tags: winapi, position

How do i get the current x and y coordinates for an hwnd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`GetWindowRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)